# FireStore for Ruby - How to subscribe to document changes

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to subscribe to changes in a firestore document in ruby using the [Firestore API for Ruby](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-firestore/v0.21.1/google/cloud/firestore/documentreference)

I can get a document reference and data using the following code, but not sure how to subscribe to changes

```
# Firestore API
firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new(project_id: 'project_id', credentials: './google-cloud-key.json')

# Get a reference to a document
ref = firestore.collection('collection_name').doc('id')

# Get the actual data in the document
snapshot = ref.get

data = snapshot.exists? ? snapshot.data : nil

# From this point on, how can I subscribe to changes in the document?
```

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the [Cloud Firestore documentation for Firebase for getting realtime updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) it says the following:

> Note: Realtime listeners are **not yet supported** in the C#, Go, PHP, Python or **Ruby** client libraries.

So it looks like realtime updates/subscriptions are not yet supported in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems odd that they biggest reason for a real-time database (realtime listeners) is not supported on the different API's, I hope that it is coming soon or if that someone is aware of a work around

Comment: @DavidCruwys FYI, as of now, they support realtime listeners in Ruby and most languages with GCP client libraries. According to their docs, it's just PHP they're missing support for realtime listeners right now.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been recently added to the fire-store client library.

You can use DocumentReference#listen to listen to changes in the document

```
require "google/cloud/firestore"

firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new

# Get a document reference
nyc_ref = firestore.doc "cities/NYC"

listener = nyc_ref.listen do |snapshot|
  puts "The population of #{snapshot[:name]} "
  puts "is #{snapshot[:population]}."
end

# When ready, stop the listen operation and close the stream.
listener.stop
```